# Forticlient VPN from mac CLI

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, vpn

I'd like to make a script to connect to different SSL VPN's from macOS.  I cannot find any info as to how to connect VPN's via command line?  Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 14):

There is actually a way. First, install [openfortivpn](https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn) via [brew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install openfortivpn
```

Then, connect as such:

```
sudo openfortivpn <server_ip>:<server_port> -u <username> -p <password>
```

Comment: Works for me. I had to add a configuration file since the password can't be visible. The syntax is:
$ sudo openfortivpn -c configuration_file

Comment: For me, it seems to connect successfully on command line, but the network itself is not usable (from a browser). The Forticlient Console also does not update it as connected (In Windows OS it connects fine)

Answer (score 3):

After some research I have come to conclusion there is no FortiClient CLI for MAC OS. In other words there is no commands for FortiClient in terminal. Still you can use terminal for Backup/Restore/Export for FortiClient VPN configuration. You can use this link for reference:
[FortiClient XML Reference Guide](https://docs.fortinet.com/document/forticlient/6.0.1/xml-reference-guide/749677/back-up-and-restore-command-line-utility-commands-and-syntax)